# Java CentOs File path with special characters and spaces FileNotFound

Tags: java, centos

I'm having trouble accessing certain Files in java. Altough the files get loaded of the Filesystem using folder.listFiles() etc...

The problem I have is that some files have special characters and spaces.

Example:

```
     /test folder/subtestfolder/>> my file.txt
```

I think java translates it to:

```
     '/test folder/subtestfolder/?? my file.txt'
```

To pass it to CentOs. But because there are spaces and special characters theres no analyzing on the ??. **Is it possible to force to use the >> or encode it?**

This is the error I get from a library I use:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /test folder/subtestfolder/?? my file.txt(No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)...
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape them using `\`

like `/test folder/subtestfolder/\>\> my file.txt`

Comment: Hi, I haven't tested you're solution but the other one works for each file and doesn't require escaping!