# File not found altough it exists (Java)

Tags: java, resources, java-io

I am trying to read javascript file contents from Java code. Here is my code:

```java
 String javascript = "";
 URL url = getClass().getResource("/elementController.js");
 System.out.println(url.toString());
 try {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(url.getPath()));
     while (sc.hasNext()) {
         javascript += sc.nextLine() + "\n";
     }
     sc.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

System.out.println prints the following:
file:**/C:/Users/J%c3%bcesse/IdeaProjects/JavaFxProject/target/classes/elementController.js**

As a result of this code execution I get the following stacktrace:

```java
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\J%c3%bcesse\IdeaProjects\ThesisProject\target\classes\elementController.js (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
at gui.WebViewWindow$MyBrowser.<init>(WebViewWindow.java:82)
at gui.WebViewWindow.display(WebViewWindow.java:58)
```

But when I go to the directory where the javascript file resides, I can see that it is there. Picture of the directory:

[image: Directory structure]

I don't know why I am getting this error, even though the file exists there.
Any suggestions?

Comment: try the full path

Comment: You can't tag this question as [tag:javascript] just because you have a `String` named `javascript` ;)

Comment: its tagged as java,

Comment: A URL is not a filename, and a resource is not a file. Use the URL's input stream.

Comment: @SyedBaryalay I edited the post and fixed it :P

Comment: When Java says the file was not found, though there exists a file with that name anywhere, then it's obviously placed in the wrong directory. Research where exactly the method expects your file and move it to that location.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768695/java-centos-file-path-with-special-characters-and-spaces-filenotfound

Comment: `J%c3%bcesse` is a _URL encoded_ path -- the filesystem path does not contain the string `%c3%bc` because, as @EJP said, a URL is not a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL is not a filename, and a resource is not a file. You can't use `FileInputStream` on it for both reasons. Once the resource is packaged into your JAR file the whole scheme will collapse. You need to use the resource's input stream:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/elementController.js");
System.out.println(url.toString());
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
```

As you're only reading lines, there is no good reason to use a `Scanner` actually: you may as well use a `BufferReader`.

Comment: Yeah. This is a good explanation. I managed to get it working by using full path with new File("full path"), but I also wanted to know about packaging (distribution of my jar). This code snippet seems to do the trick. I guess I need to make this file system stuff more clear to me.

Comment: It's as simple as this: a JAR file isn't a file system.

Comment: @EJP With the path api, it is.

Comment: @killjoy And with the API the OP is using it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The character `ü` is getting converted to `%c3%bc` in URL format. When you try to use that path as a regular file path for file input, however, instead of opening URL input stream, the reverse decoding of `%c3%bc` doesn't happen, and the file names don't match, hence the `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Altough the @EJP answer was a solution I also upvote this one too, because of explanation of conversion of unusual characters. Thank you for your help.